# Restkit getting different data for two table view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

With restkit I'm trying to get data for two tables view (inbox, sent), tables view controller identical in their functionality, except that they refer to different web api.
In each table view controller I configure and initialize restkit and makes a request for getting INBOX or SENT data, according to the table
Everything works great, but only has a specific table, only that which is initialized first, for another error occurs

`E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:213 GET 'http://myhost/sent/' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.9469s mapping=0.0000s total=0.9963s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0x11001a040 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http://myhost/sent/', which failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://myhost/sent/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myhost/sent/, NSUnderlyingError=0x11007f790 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched.", keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.`

Configure restkit in my code:

```
// initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

RKEntityMapping *sentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Sent" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
sentMapping .identificationAttributes = @[ @"message_id" ];
[sentMapping  addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"objectId":@"message_id",
                                                       @"ToUserName":@"email_to",
                                                       @"createdAt":@"date_send",
                                                       @"Read":@"read"
                                                       }];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:sentMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:@"/sent/"
                                            keyPath:@"results"
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i don't think this has much to do with your tableview. probably something with the mapping.

Comment: @YarGnawh correct initialize restkit for second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which failed to match all (0) response descriptors

You haven't configured any response descriptors, or at least none which match the request URL path pattern (presumably `sent/`) and method (GET).

Check the descriptor registrations and the filtering criteria (path pattern, method and key path).

Comment: thank you for fast response. but in my case, it all depends on what kind of table view I first open it, then that shall be completed without errors, but when I open another table view this error occurs, I think my problem is in the correct to initialize restkit in these two different cases

Comment: Are you calling `[[RKObjectManager alloc] init...` twice in your code and using `sharedManager` anywhere?

Comment: of course! I think I start to understand my mistake

Comment: Should I call it only once, example in appDelegate?

Comment: Yes once, but not in the app delegate (born twice, and retain a reference in a property).

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
It is simple!

First, need initialise RESTKit in as example AppDelegate

```
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.myhost"];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
............
```

And then you may use RESTKit as you need
As example call in view controller:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
RKEntityMapping *sentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Sent" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
sentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"message_id" ];
[sentMapping  addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"objectId"  :@"message_id",
                                                   @"ToUserName":@"email_to",
                                                   @"createdAt" :@"date_send",
                                                   @"Subject"   :@"subject",
                                                   @"Message"   :@"message",
                                                   }];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:sentMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:@"/sent/"
                                            keyPath:@"results"
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
...............
```

and further as required to work with RESTKit